# JSONModel accept Object and String

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, jsonmodel

I have this in my SongModel.h:

```
@interface SongModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *artist;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *start;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *end;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *artistLink;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *songLink;
@end
```

Because artistLink and songLink are not well formatted in (not mine) JSON.
It can be a string or an empty object, how can I parse this?

An "id" type is not supported by JSONModel

Answer (score 0):

I would probably accept and `id` then set it either to `[NSNull null]` when it cannot be parsed, or set it to the `NSString` when it can be parsed.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) id artistLink;`

```
if (canBeParsed) {
    artistLink = @"The string";
} else {
    artistLink = [NSNull null];
}
```

EDIT: Martin R. brought up a good point, and thats certainly another way of doing it.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *artistLink`

```
if (canBeParsed) {
    artistLink = @"The string";
} else {
    artistLink = nil;
}
```

Comment: Why not declare as `NSString *` and set to `nil`, if object could not be parsed? That allows better compiler checking when the string property is accessed.

Comment: I am new to objective c and follow a lot of tutorials, but how can I accomplish such a thing? It now says Property type of SongModel.artistLink is not supported by JSONModel.

I found this in the source on Github:
//type not allowed - programmer mistaked -> exception
                    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"JSONModelProperty type not allowed"
                                                   reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Property type of %@.%@ is not supported by JSONModel.", self.className, p.name]
                                                 userInfo:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by:

```
NSRegularExpression *replaceEmptyObject = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"{}/g" options:0 error:nil];
jsonString = [replaceEmptyObject stringByReplacingMatchesInString:jsonString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [jsonString length]) withTemplate:@"\"\""];
```

maybe not the most beautiful way, but it works for me.
Those are the only empty objects in this json.